# Find an arithmetic sequence which...

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find an arithmetic sequence with $5$ terms which sum of them are $15$ and if multiply all terms the answer would be $1155$

$a$ is the first term.

So

$a(a + d)(a + 2d)(a + 3d)(a + 4d) =1155$

And

$\frac{5(2a + 4d)}{2} = 15$

I could replace $a$ with $3 -2d$ but it's very time consuming! So what's the easy way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the number of terms of the Arithmetic sequence is odd, let the terms be $a,a\pm d,a\pm 2d$

So, $a-d+a-2d+a+a+d+a+2d=5\implies a=1$

and $(a-d)(a-2d)(a)(a+d)(a+2d)=1155$

$$\iff(a^2-d^2)(a^2-4d^2)=1155$$

Had the number of terms of the Arithmetic sequence been even,  we could take the terms to be $a\pm d,a\pm3d,a\pm5d$ etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is a quick and slightly unorthodox approach.

By inspection, 
$$1155=1\times 3\times 5\times 7\times 11$$
The five numbers would have formed a nice AP apart from the missing $9$. Also, they sum to $27$, which is $12$ in excess of the required $15$.

Let's try and even out the spacing by making some of the numbers negative. 
As the excess of $12$ conveniently happens to be twice the sum of $1$ and $5$, we'll make both these numbers negative. This results in all numbers being evenly spaced out, i.e. a nice AP.

We now have 
$$(-5)\times (-1)\times3\times 7\times 11=1155$$
and
$$(-5)+(-1)+3+7+11=15$$
as required...

*Voila!*